# What database for crawler/scraper?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I am currently researching what database to use for a project I am working on. Hopefully you guys can give me some hints.

The project is an automated web crawler that checks websites as per a user's request, scrapes data under certain circumstances, and creates log files of what was done.

Requirements:

- Only few tables with few columns; predefining columns is no problem
- No overly complex associations between models
- Huge amount of date & time based queries
- Due to logging, database will grow rapidly and use up a lot of space
- Should be able to scale over multiple servers
- Fields contain mostly ids (int), strings (around 200-500 characters max), and unix timestamps
- Two different types of servers will simultaneously read/write data directly to/from it:

  - One(/later more) rails app that takes user input and displays results upon request
  - One(/later more) Node.js server that functions as the executing crawler/scraper. It will have enough load to run continuously and make dozens of database queries every second.

I assume it will neither be a graph database (no complex associations), nor a memory based key/value store (too much data to hold in cached). I'm still on the fence for every other type of database I could find, each seems to have it's merits.

So, any advice from the pros how I should decide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would agree with Vladimir that you would want to consider a document-based database for this scenario.  I am most familiar with MongoDB.  My reasons for using it here are as follows:

1. Your 'schema requirements' of "only a few tables with few columns" fits well with the NoSQL nature of MongoDB.
2. Same as above for "no overly complex associations between nodes" -- you will want to decide whether you'd prefer nested documents or using dbref (I prefer the former)
3. Huge amount of time-based data (and other scaling requirements) - MongoDB scales well via sharding or partitioning
4. Read/write access - this is why I am recommending MongoDB over something like Hadoop.  The interactive query requirement is best met by something other than a Hadoop-style store, as this type of storage is designed for batch (rather than interactive query) requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Google built a database called "BigTable" for crawling, indexing and the search related business. They released a paper about it (google for "BigTable" if you're interested). There are several open source implementations for bigtable-like designs, one of them is [Hypertable](http://Hypertable.com). We have a blog posting describing a crawler/indexer implementation (http://hypertable.com/blog/sehrchcom_a_structured_search_engine_powered_by_hypertable/) written by the guys from sehrch.com. And looking at your requirements: all of them are supported and are common use cases.

(disclaimer: i work for hypertable.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. If it's your product I can't trust that this is an unbiased recommendation but I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: sure, that's why i added the disclaimer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at document-oriented database like a [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).